# Creating div in function (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an exercise where I have to make an input and a button. When I click the button, there has to be created a div/span below, which prints the text which is in input. If I change the text in input, it has to be refreshed in that div/span only when I click the button again. I tried to do it with `makeDiv` function, but it doesn't do anything. I made `console.log(event.target.value)` and it handles the text which is in input, but nothing happens then.

My code:

```
import {useState} from "react"
function About() {
    
    const [initialValue,setInitialValue] = useState('')
    const handleValueChange = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value)
        setInitialValue(event.target.value)
    }
    const makeDiv = () => {
        return (<div>Value: {initialValue}</div>)
    }
    return(
    <div>
        

        <button onClick={makeDiv}>click me</button>
       <div><input type="text" onChange={handleValueChange} /></div>


    </div>
        )
}
export default About
```

edit:

What if I wanted to make an exercise very similar to that, but now, I have to add `<li>text in input</li>` to `<ul>` each time I click the button. So when I click the button, I add one `li` to the list, I tried like this, but it doesn't compile:

```
import {useState} from "react"
function About() {
   
   
   

    const [initialValueLastExercise, setInitialValueLastExercise] = useState([])
    const [ValueLE, setValueLE] = useState([])
    const handleValueChangeLE = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value)
        setInitialValueLastExercise([...initialValueLastExercise, event.target.value])
    }
    const showListWithText = () => {
        setShouldDisplayText(true)
        setValueLE(initialValueLastExercise)
    }


    return(
    <div>
   

       
        <button onClick={showListWithText}>click me to refresh the list</button>
        <div><input type="text" onChange={handleValueChangeLE} /></div>
        {shouldDisplayText && <div><ul>
            {
                
                for (let i =0; i<initialValueLastExercise.length; i++) {
                <li>{initialValueLastExercise[i]}</li>

                }




        }</div></ul>}


    </div>
        )
}
export default About
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will refresh the value of the div on button click only as you have mentioned in the question.

```
import {useState} from "react"
function App() {
    
    const [initialValue,setInitialValue] = useState('')
    const [displayText, setDisplayText] = useState(false)
    const [Value,setValue] = useState('')
    const handleValueChange = (event) => {
        setInitialValue(event.target.value)
    }
    const showText = () => {setDisplayText(true)
    setValue(initialValue)};
return(
    <div>
       <button onClick={showText}>click me</button>
       <div><input type="text" onChange={handleValueChange} /></div>
       {displayText && <div>Value: {Value}</div>}
    </div>
        )
}
export default App
```

**Solution for the Edited Question.**

```
import {useState} from "react"
function App() {
    
    const [initialValue,setInitialValue] = useState('')
    const [displayText, setDisplayText] = useState(false)
    const [Value,setValue] = useState([])
    const handleValueChange = (event) => {
        setInitialValue(event.target.value)
    }
    const showText = () => {setDisplayText(true)
    setValue([...Value,initialValue])};
return(
    <div>
       <button onClick={showText}>click me</button>
       <div><input type="text" onChange={handleValueChange} /></div>
       <ul>{displayText && Value.length > 0  && 
         Value.map((i) => {
          return <li>Value: {i}</li>
       })}</ul>
    </div>
        )
      }
export default App
```

Comment: I edited my post, because I have another very similar exercise to that one, but again it doesn't want to compile

Answer (score 0):

**1st possibility - close to your code source**

Don't forget to bind `initialValue` to the input and to add makeDiv content to the JSX :

```
return (
<div>
  <button onClick={makeDiv}>click me</button>
  <input type="text" onChange={handleValueChange} value={initialValue} />
  {makeDiv}
</div>
)
```

**2nd possibility - with another approach**

```
return (
<div>
  <button onClick={makeDiv}>click me</button>
  <input type="text" onChange={handleValueChange} value={initialValue} />
  {initialValue && <div>{initialValue}</div>}
</div>
)
```

Comment: it didn't change anything :/

Comment: it fails to compile now - what's that `makeJSX`?

Comment: sorry it was ```makeDiv```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create another state variable which indicates whether the `div` you're trying to make should be displayed and then render it conditionally. Something like

```
import {useState} from "react"
function About() {
    
    const [initialValue,setInitialValue] = useState('')
    const [shouldDisplayText, setShouldDisplayText] = useState(false)
    const handleValueChange = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value)
        setInitialValue(event.target.value)
    }
    const showDivWithText = () => setShouldDisplayText(true);
return(
    <div>
        

        <button onClick={showDivWithText}>click me</button>
       <div><input type="text" onChange={handleValueChange} /></div>
       {shouldDisplayText && <div>Value: {initialValue}</div>}


    </div>
        )
}
export default About
```

Comment: it doesn't work well, because it refreshes the div immedietaly when we change the text in input - it has to refresh it only when I click the button.

Comment: Pardon me, I did not read the description of the problem properly. In that case, just keep another state variable of the text you need to display in the `div` instead of keeping a variable of whether it should be displayed, and every time you click the button update it (instead of `shouldDisplayText` call the variable `currentlyDisplayedText` or something and whenever you click the button the function should be `() => setCurrentlyDisplayedText(initialValue)`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fundamentally wrong.

You should:

- Store **all** the data about the component in the state
- Render the output based on the state

So:

You need two state variables:

- currentInputValue (because you need to store the value to display and edit in input)
- selectedValue (because you need to store the value to be displayed in the div)

When `onChange` fires, update `currentInputValue` with the value of the input.

When `onClick` fires, update `selectedValue` with the current value of `currentInputValue`

When you return your data, include something like:

```
{selectedValue && <div>{selectedValue}</div>}
```

… to output a div containing the selected value only if there is a truthy value (the default empty string isn't truthy so the div won't be output then)